# Get Video Thumbnail and Display in ListView(To Android Genius Alone)

Tags: android, listview

I currently have a method to fetch all the videos from the device and display in a `listview`. Currently I only show the album name and title with a default image for the thumbnail which repeats in all the rows of the `listview`. The method to do that is

```
    try {
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                // Use a template that displays a text view
                R.layout.media_select_row,
                null,
                // Map from database columns...
                new String[] {
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media._ID},
                    // To widget ids in the row layout...
                new int[] {
                    R.id.row_album,
                    R.id.row_title,
                    R.id.row_icon,},
                0);

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        getListView().setItemsCanFocus(true);

        // Normal click - open the editor
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View view,
                    int position,
                    long id) {

                Cursor c = mAdapter.getCursor();
                int dataIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                String filename = c.getString(dataIndex);

                videoFilename = filename;

                String substr = videoFilename.substring(videoFilename.length() - 3);

                if(substr.equals("mp4")) {
                    if(callPath == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(DubVideoList.this, DubStudio.class);
                        intent.putExtra("videoPath", videoFilename);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if(callPath == 2){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(DubVideoList.this, DubStudioBeta.class);
                        intent.putExtra("videoPath", videoFilename);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(DubVideoList.this,getString(R.string.mp4_support),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        mInternalCursor = null;
        mExternalCursor = null;
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(INTERNAL_CURSOR_ID, null, this);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(EXTERNAL_CURSOR_ID, null, this);

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // No permission to retrieve video?
        Log.e("SecurityError", e.toString());

        // TODO error 1
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // No permission to retrieve video?
        Log.e("IllegalArgument", e.toString());

        // TODO error 2
    }

    mAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
          if (view.getId() == R.id.row_icon) {
                setSoundIconFromCursor((ImageView) view, cursor);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now I need to replace the default image for each cell with the Video's Thumbnail ? Is there a way to do that ? I have given the row's `XML` also for your reference. Thanks in advance.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/row_icon"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_width="40dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
      android:src="@drawable/filmicon"
      android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/row_title"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:shadowColor="#999999"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/row_album"
            android:textColor="#ff1bbcff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

       </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the thumbnail, you can use this code

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(video_path,
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: just you have to pass videos url or path to get the thumbnail... you can place this in the Adapter getView() method and show that image instead of default image

Comment: I am not using any custom `adapter`. So how do I do it ? Please give me a proper solution. I have all my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to add video thumb in listview.

Method :1

> Bitmap bMap= ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("local file path" ,
>   MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
>                MViewHolder.imageThumb.setImageBitmap(bMap);

Method :2

Use Glide

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

Glide
    .with( context )
    .load( Uri.fromFile( new File( filePath ) ) )
    .into( MViewHolder.imageThumb );